# Why do `x + y` and `*x + *y` give the same result when x and y are references?

Tags: rust

I have to implement a function that adds two numbers:

```
fn add(x: &i32, y: &i32) -> i32 {
    println!("x is: {}, y is {}", x, y);
    println!("*x is: {}, *y is {}", *x, *y);
    x + y
}

fn double(x: i32) -> i32 {
    add(&x, &x)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(double(5), 10);
    println!("Success!");
}
```

The output is:

```
x is: 5, y is 5
*x is: 5, *y is 5
Success!
```

Per my understanding, the `add` function should not be able to perform `x+y` as they both are addresses. Only `*x + *y` should work as it dereferences the addresses and provides the values stored there. However, both statements yield the same result. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

The [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20i32%3E-1) trait (operator `+`) is implemented for `&i32`s as well as `i32`s. In fact, you can have any combination:

- [`i32 + i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3Ci32%3E)
- [`i32 + &i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20i32%3E)
- [`&i32 + i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3Ci32%3E-1)
- [`&i32 + &i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20i32%3E-1)

They all do the same thing, they are there for convenience.

See also:

- [Why do I need to dereference a variable when comparing it but not when doing arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100030/why-do-i-need-to-dereference-a-variable-when-comparing-it-but-not-when-doing-ari)
- [How could rust multiply &i32 with i32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739755/how-could-rust-multiply-i32-with-i32)
- [Why does &v[1] + &v[2] have the same result as v[1] + v[2] in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142322/why-does-v1-v2-have-the-same-result-as-v1-v2-in-rust)
- [Understanding (automatic?) Deref/coercion when adding references and values of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360850/understanding-automatic-deref-coercion-when-adding-references-and-values-of-n)

Comment: Also, the `println!` macro ultimately expands to a method call—and, as with any method call, Rust recursively performs deref coercion on its arguments until it reaches the expected type (in the case of the `{}` format specifier, this is anything that implements the `Display` trait).